# MongoDB schema for visit and like

Tags: mongodb, database-design, schema

MySQL serves as our primary database, while MongoDB is employed for handling intensive write operations. I have been tasked with implementing a system for tracking visits and likes on products. The product data is stored in MySQL, but the visit and like data will be managed in MongoDB. To ensure uniqueness for likes and visits, we also need to monitor the users who have liked or visited the products. Therefore, I have devised the following schemas for implementation:

### First Schema:

```
MySQL / Products Table
-----
product_id: 1,
...

product_id: 2,
...

---

MongoDB / Products Collection
---
product_id: 1
likes: [user_id_1, user_id_2, user_id_3... ]
visits: [user_id_1, user_id_2, user_id_3... ]

product_id: 2
likes: [user_id_1, user_id_2, user_id_3... ]
visits: [user_id_1, user_id_2, user_id_3... ]
```

### Second Schema:

```
MySQL / Products Table
-----
product_id: 1,
...

product_id: 2,
...

---

MongoDB / Likes Collection
---
user_id: 1
product_id: 1

user_id: 2
product_id: 2

user_id: 3
product_id: 3

MongoDB / Visits Collection
---
user_id: 1
product_id: 1

user_id: 2
product_id: 2

user_id: 3
product_id: 3
```

I am uncertain whether these schemas align with MongoDB's best practices, so I am seeking guidance here. Are there any issues with these schemas?

Comment: This is too broad for StackOverflow and [probably better on DBA.se](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "***Data Modelling*** and database-design, including referential-integrity". But since you mentioned _"system for tracking visits and likes on products."_ - don't over-normalise in Mongo. The second schema is better suited to traditional RDBMS. However, if you have too many likes & visits, have immensely long arrays of userIDs in the First schema will set you over the 16 MB limit, and later the 100 MB limit. Track Visits & Likes in separate collections, not the same one.